# How can I test a private or fileprivate function in project

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I want to write some unit testing code for a manager class, the function I would write for is using some small `private` functions. I will prepare a lot if I testing the `public` function, so I want to test those `private` functions. But in test target I can't call the private function directly.

So I wanna ask, is there's a way to test them without change them from `private` to `internal` or `public`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I wanna ask, is there's a way to test them without change them from private to `internal` or `public`?

Add an internal function that does nothing but call the private function. Probably it's best to do it in an extension:

```
class Foo
{
    fileprivate func myPrivateFunction(p: Int) { ... }
}

extension Foo 
{
    internal func testMyPrivateFunction(p: Int) 
    {
        myPrivateFunc(p: p)
    }
}
```

You can probably find a way of using conditional compilation to omit the extension for release builds e.g.

```
#if DEBUG
extension Foo 
{
    internal func testMyPrivateFunction(p: Int) 
    {
        myPrivateFunc(p: p)
    }
}
#endif
```

Not tested the conditional thing to see if it works, it's borrowed from here https://ericasadun.com/2018/04/18/forcing-compiler-errors-in-swift/

Comment: Maybe it's the better solution for now. I add a compile condition `#if TESTABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no. There isn't a "VisibleForTesting" tag in Swift as there is in java.

However you can define a protocol which your manager class then implements including only the methods you want to test.

For example if your manager has a function called createViewModel that calls several private methods testing that the viewModel created matches that of what we expect we have implicitly tested the private methods work. You can set up your manager with different initial conditions to test all varieties and edge cases

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `@testable` imports. From Apple's documentation:

> When you add the `@testable` attribute to an import statement for a
>   module compiled with testing enabled, you activate the elevated access
>   for that module in that scope. Classes and class members marked as
>   internal or public behave as if they were marked open. Other entities
>   marked as internal act as if they were declared public.

Comment: I'm using `@testable` already, but still can't access `fileprivate` or `private` functions.

Comment: `@testable` will only elevate `internal` to `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are the solution.

This solution is a bit more complicated than the others, but can help you for multiple purposes, like uncoupling modules on your app.

Let's say you have a class `Foo` which has an object of type `Bar`, and you need to call `doStuff()`.

Create a **Protocol** for Bar. So Foo is decoupled from Bar and becomes fully testable without exposing its content to Foo. Something like this:

```
protocol BarProtocol {
   func doStuff()
}

class Bar:BarProtocol {
   func doStuff() {
      print("Hello world")
   }
}

class Foo {
   var bar:BarProtocol

   init() {
      self.bar = Bar()
      self.bar.doStuff()
   }
}
```

Comment: What I mark the functions as `private` purpose is, I don't want others to use them. So I want to keep them invisible. Unfortunately, it's invisible for test project too.

Comment: Others should use your protocol not directly the implementation, this way your methods are hidden for them but visible for tests. Is part of the Dependency Inversion Principle. You can learn more about it: https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: This doesn't really help in the stated aim to test private properties and functions.